# Define default route without trailing slash in RAML

Tags: yaml, raml

We're defining our service(s) using RAML. Here's a partial definition:

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: API
version: v1
baseUri: http://localhost:9000/api/{version}
```

We want to serve the API entry point on `/api/v1` (without a slash).

How can we do that?

RAML only allows us to specify a route including a trailing slash:

```
/:
  get:
    ...
```

I also tried

```
"":
  get:
    ...
```

But RAML doesn't like it, although I think it's valid YAML.

Here's the error message:

```
unknown property 
while validating root properties
unknown property 
  in "api.raml", line 106, column 1:
    "":
    ^
  at Constructor.__dirname.Validator.Validator.validate_root_properties     (/src/api-spec/node_modules/raml-parser/lib/validator.js:640:23)
  at Constructor.__dirname.Validator.Validator.validate_document     (/src/api-spec/node_modules/raml-parser/lib/validator.js:76:20)
  at Constructor.__dirname.Composer.Composer.composeRamlTree     (/src/api-spec/node_modules/raml-parser/lib/composer.js:79:14)
  at Constructor.composeRamlTree (/src/api-    spec/node_modules/raml-parser/lib/composer.js:5:61)
  at /src/api-spec/node_modules/raml-    parser/lib/raml.js:224:16
```

Comment: If you use `/` did you get forced to have a trailing slash by some RAML tool?